# Did aesthetics play a role in the construction of the Standard Model?

Tags: physics, theoretical-physics, particle-physics

The Standard Model is a sophisticated mathematical framework to capture the behavior of elementary particles. It is a dream castle which is built on loose sand and every change in its construction or shifting of the sand will lead to a collapse of the castle. At the same time, there are many possibilities to keep the castle intact and to prevent the loose sand from shifting.

I was wondering. When the castle was constructed, were aestetical features for the castle taken into consideration? Like a beautifull unification of the weak and electromagnetic force, which is part of the model but can easily be proven to be an artificial unification, based on math only and with no relation to reality whatsoever.

Now, in constructing a real castle beauty considerations are certainly present. Were they too in constructing the Standard Model?

Comment: Some argue that aesthetics is an unhealthy influence in our physical theories.  For example, Sabine Hossenfelder's pop-science book *Lost in Math: How Beauty Leads Physics Astray*.

Comment: @Nick I saw the video where she made her point. I think these considerations can be very fruitfull though. Equations have a kind of beauty. Up to a certain point though. You can always consider it but I think that in the standard model it has gone a bit to far.

Comment: Mathematical beauty has certainly been a fruitful guide so far.

Comment: "But can easily be proven to be an artificial unification"??? These sorts of things cannot be proven or disproven at all, what is "real" and what "artificial" is a matter of taste. Yes, the whole enterprise of unification is driven, in part, by aesthetic considerations, physicists find multiple "fundamental" entities without a common root distasteful. But the Standard Model is a chimera of the electroweak theory and chromodynamics crudely welded together, not a dream castle. Which is why physicists can't wait to replace it with grand unification or, better yet, supergravity.

Comment: @Conifold Experiment can easily prove it wrong. Adherence to the unification of EM and the weak force can even limit experiment. Experiments that show that the weak force is not basic but residue.

Comment: @Conifold Whats the difference between a chimera and a dream castle? Can a chimera live in a dream castle?

Comment: [Chimeras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chimera_(mythology)) are spliced together from disparate parts.

Comment: @Conifold Sounds like a horror movie...

Comment: @Conifold Anyway, in this case its not a matter of taste.

Comment: @Conifold So every attempt for unification will only lead you further away from reality. If they want to unify  its up to them. But they will only be looking for ghost particles *(if extra particles show up).

Comment: @Conifold *what is "real" and what "artificial" is a matter of taste.* Huh???